# Encountering seg fault in wininet ftp program

Tags: c++, windows, ftp, wininet

So i found this c++ program and i thought i would use it to automate backing up my files to my desktop ftp server but it always runs into the same seg fault problem, After checking the ftp server logs i can see that is does actually connect to the ftp server and log in with the user name and password but it when it reaches the actual upload part it crashes.

I ran it through the debugger in dev c++ and it says "Access violation (Seg faut)"

Is this a bug in wininet? and if so is there some sort of workaround?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

int send(const char * ftp, const char * user, const char * pass, const char * pathondisk, char * nameonftp)
{

HINTERNET hInternet;
HINTERNET hFtpSession;
hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT,NULL,NULL,0);
if(hInternet==NULL)
{
    cout << GetLastError();
    //system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}
hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet,
(LPTSTR)ftp, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
(LPTSTR)user, (LPTSTR)pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,
INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
if(hFtpSession==NULL)
{
    cout << GetLastError();
    //system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}
Sleep(1000);
char * buf=nameonftp;
strcat(buf,".txt");
if (!FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, (LPTSTR)pathondisk, (LPTSTR)buf, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0)) {
    cout << GetLastError();//this is never reached
    return 1;
}
Sleep(1000);
InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
return 0;
}

int main() {
send("127.0.0.1","testuser","test","file.pdf","backup");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not attempt to modify string literals. Even if they were modifyable, `strcat(buf,".txt");` do cause out-of-bounds access.

Comment: `cout << GetLastError();//this is never reached` why... because of the error?

Comment: @MikeCAT yes the program crashed before it can print GetLastError(); to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not modify string literals. Copy the string to a new buffer to edit the contents.

Also, you should use `hogeA()` APIs to have the system use ANSI charset explicitly.

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using std::cout;

int send(const char * ftp, const char * user, const char * pass, const char * pathondisk, const char * nameonftp)
{

    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if(hInternet==NULL)
    {
        cout << GetLastError();
        //system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }
    hFtpSession = InternetConnectA(hInternet,
        ftp, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
        user, pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,
        INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
    if(hFtpSession==NULL)
    {
        cout << GetLastError();
        //system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    char * buf=new char[strlen(nameonftp) + 4 + 1];
    strcpy(buf, nameonftp);
    strcat(buf, ".txt");
    if (!FtpPutFileA(hFtpSession, pathondisk, buf, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0)) {
        cout << GetLastError();
        delete[] buf;
        return 1;
    }
    delete[] buf;
    Sleep(1000);
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    send("127.0.0.1", "testuser", "test", "file.pdf", "backup");
    return 0;
}
```